# How to delete a post with the react-activity-feed client?

Tags: getstream-io

How does one delete a post with the `react-activity-feed` client for `GetStream`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The StreamApp component passes a function down to the FlatFeed and the Activity component called `onRemoveActivity`. This is a function that takes an activity's id and removes that.

So you could do something like this to remove an activity:

```
<StreamApp
  apiKey=""
  appId=""
  token=""
>
  <FlatFeed
    Activity={(props) => (
      <Activity
        {...props}
        Footer={() => (
          <React.Fragment>
            <button onClick={() => props.onRemoveActivity(props.activity.id)}>
              delete
            </button>
          </React.Fragment>
        )}
      />
    )}
  />
</StreamApp>
```

Comment: Thanks! After searching `onRemoveActivity`, I now see a good collection of examples, such as one for removing activity. Super excited to see this.